# How to use if else type condition in DataFrame without loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame df:

[image]

I want: if Date1> Date2, then id1 else id2

Output:

[image]

How to complete this without using loops? Any hints pls

Comment: What do you want to do after choosing `id1` or `id2`? You can use `df.apply`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np

df['output'] = np.where(df['Date1'].gt(df['Date2']), df['Id1'], df['Id2'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps -

1. Convert the `date1` and `date2` to datetime object using the `pd.to_datetime()`

```
df['date1'] = pd.to_datetime( df.date1)
df['date2'] = pd.to_datetime( df.date2)
```

2. Initialize an empty numpy array and then iterate through the rows using df.iterrows() getting proper values into the numpy array and then add a new column.

```
import numpy as np
n = np.empty(len(df))

for row in df.iterrows():

    # row[1] has the row data
    # row[0] has the index

    if row[1]['date1'] > row[1]['date2']:
        n[row[0]] = 1
    else:
        n[row[0]] = 0
df['output'] = n
```

There are short hands for this code as well.

Comment: thanks. I am looking for the short hand code

Comment: one provided by @Mayank Porwal is good